# How do i move apps and then information from the phone to the sd card

Tags: sd-card

How do I move apps from my phone to the external memory. There is no option in settings to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try Using this app to move your application to your SD Card ([Clean Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleanmaster.mguard)). If this does not work for your device then you have to root your device so that you can apps can be moved to SD Card. If your device is rooted then try ([Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD)).